# find the missing number in the following table

Tags: mathematics

Find the missing number in the following table.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 17 | 9 |
| 3 | 21 | 7 |
| 7 | 16 | 8 |
| 6 | 10 | ? |

Answer Options:

- 10
- 12
- 15
- 16

Comment: What is your source for this puzzle, or did you make it yourself?

Comment: Figured it out, but waiting for OP to answer before I post an answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I found it one of the old competitive exam papers, I am preparing for.

Comment: @JohnClifford Answer is 16. I don't know how. That's y posted it here.

Comment: You should probably include the source in the OP, I think it's being voted down because there's no indication of where it's from. I can't see any sequence that would result in it being 16, though...

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking us the number ask us whats the pattern behind 16

Comment: 16 could be just a simple mistake. 15 appears to be the simplest answer, and I would accept it as an answer even if there was some reason that it could be 16 also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 15

because

> each row adds up to 31.

Comment: I found it in one of the old competitive exam papers, I am preparing for. Even I got 15. However, its mentioned to be 16 in the answer key.

Comment: @MansiManhas Indian book writers and even the authorities conducting the aptitude exams for lower groups posts get the answers wrong a lot. Don't bother with official answer, but use logic. I saw 15 as answer in an another book.